# selenium working as line-by-line but not in a script

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

[my python script in upper left corner , error message in the middle , when i execute line by line in the lower left corner, the right half is geckodriver log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XXhj.png)

I`m trying to run python script using selenium module to make basic automated youtube search.
I get the error show in the middle picture when I write the script as a whole but when I write the code line-by-line it works perfectly .
I tried reinstalling gecko and firefox but didn`t work .
how i installed gecko: 1)un-tar file 2) make file executable 3)mv file to usr/local/bin ...
Geckodriver 26.0.0
Firefox 75.0
ubuntu 19.10
vim 8.2

Comment: Can you provide more details on gecko driver version and your firefox version?

Comment: geckodriver 0.26.0 firefox 75.0

Comment: Well the log tells you what the problem is. Running firefox as root in a regular user session is not supported.

Comment: i run script as sudo because when i run as user i get " PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'  "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log is pretty clear about the error, **you cannot run** `geckodriver` as `root`, you've to run it under a different user, which you can do using `sudo -H -u`, i.e.:

```
chown someuser:someuser /path/to/script.py
sudo -H -u someuser python /path/to/script.py
```